# How to get dynamic href value in html using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have created a accordion. Actually I have click the accordion dynamically creating that but i want the dynamic value of **href value** how to make this.

MY HTML code:

```
<div class="lv-header-alt clearfix bgm-{{::hl.accountThemes[hl.theme]}} c-white" 
     ng-class="{'hide': oc.hideDates == 1}">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="c-white" style="display: block;font-size: 23px;margin-left: -10px;" 
       data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"> week</a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

I want Exactly This Format:

```
<div class="lv-header-alt clearfix bgm-{{::hl.accountThemes[hl.theme]}} c-white" 
     ng-class="{'hide': oc.hideDates == 1}">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="c-white" style="display: block;font-size: 23px;margin-left: -10px;" 
       data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"> week</a>
    </h4>
</div>

<div class="lv-header-alt clearfix bgm-{{::hl.accountThemes[hl.theme]}} c-white" 
     ng-class="{'hide': oc.hideDates == 1}">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="c-white" style="display: block;font-size: 23px;margin-left: -10px;"
           data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2"> week</a>
        </h4>
</div>


<div class="lv-header-alt clearfix bgm-{{::hl.accountThemes[hl.theme]}} c-white"
     ng-class="{'hide': oc.hideDates == 1}">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="c-white" style="display: block;font-size: 23px;margin-left: -10px;"
       data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3"> week</a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't truly understand your requirement, but here is a simple way you can create Accordion:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sarvesh, Accordion is okay , i have passing dynamically Accordion i want to get dynamic Id how will get this.

Comment: Now the dynamic accordion working but i need to pass dynamic id or dynamic href value

Comment: Can you do something like this:
HTML : <a id="a1" href="test1" />
JS: 
var x = document.getElementById('a1');
x.href = 'test2';

Comment: dynamically it won't happened ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try using ng-repeat**

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in awesomeThings">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" toggle target="collapse{{ $index + 1 }}">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    {{ item }}
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse{{ $index + 1 }}" toggleable active-class="in" exclusion-group="accordion1" default="active" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <!-- ... -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> </div>
```